# ToDouble() is not working?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement the following lines of code but it gives me errors:

```
var distanceTravelRight = 10.0;
var tick = DateTime.Now.Ticks();
var velLeft = distanceTravelRight / tick.ToDouble;
```

> Non-invocable member 'System.DateTime.Ticks' cannot be used like a method.
>
> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToDouble' and no extension method 'ToDouble' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I would appreciate if anyone could point out the problems so that I can learn!

Comment: What are you expecting to *achieve* with this? I suspect the `DateTime.Ticks` property (not method) doesn't do what you expect it to. Hint: has the subject really been travelling since 1AD?

Comment: Why do you need to convert `long` to `double` when you already have one side of `/` operator to be of floating point type?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Seems like a `Stopwatch` or `TimeSpan` would be more useful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ticks` is a property, not a method so you do not need to call it with parenthesis `()`.

```
var tick = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Also, to convert a string to a double, use `double.TryParse`.

```
double yourDouble;
if (double.TryParse(yourString, out yourDouble)) 
{
   // It is safe to use `yourDouble` here
}
```

Comment: Please add an example how to use Double.TryParse().

Comment: @abatishchev, why not take a look at the documentation for TryParse??

Comment: Also I'd use just Double.Parse() in the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Double.Parse() will work fine unless the string is not a valid double, in which case you'll get an exception.

Comment: @abatishchev `TryParse` is safer.

Comment: OP likely asks for `(double)ticks`, also I have no idea why that would be necessary...

Comment: Will DateTime.Now.Ticks give me a string?

Comment: @user3777839 no: it will give you a `long`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @user3777839: It won't.

Comment: `TryParse()` isn't safer, it's faster in case of an error, But adds complexity for a beginner such as `out` and additional `if`

Comment: @DanielA.White: Yes, it does that because it doesn't really know the type of `ticks`, due to the first error. There isn't *really* a string involved - that's just the compiler guessing (incorrectly).